# htaccess url rewrite multiple url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've a problem to rewrite url in my site with .htaccess

index.php

```
$op = $_GET['op'];

switch ($op) {

     case "src":
        include("src.php");
     break;

     case "dts":
         include ("dts.php");
     break;

     default:
        include("home.php");
     break;
}
```

Link to rewrite

```
index.php?op=src
index.php?op=dts&idric=20&sp=2
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?op=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/idric/(.*)/sp/(.*)/$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2&sp=$3 [L,QSA]
```

If I write the first link www.mysite.com/src/ it shows the correct page (src.php),
but if I write the second url www.mysite.com/dts/idric/20/sp/2/ it shows the default page (home.php).

Comment: Do you have something like this in you code `$op = $_GET['op'];` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applier to very next `RewriteRule`. And your last rule gets overridden by previous one.

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L,NC]
# rule to ignore files and directories from all rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/idric/([^/]+)/sp/([^/]+)/$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2&sp=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ index.php?op=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately in this manner nothing works, not even the first link mysite.com/src/

Comment: With these rules on my Apache `localhost/dts/idric/20/sp/2/` gave me `$_GET['op']` as `dts` and ``localhost/src/` gave as `src` so something wrong on your side. Did you copy/paste as shown? Are there any other rules too?

Comment: actually my test url is this localhost/test/src/ and localhost/test/dts/idric/20/sp/2/

Comment: .htaccess is inside test dir

Comment: Sorry , I made a mistake and now it seems to be ok. If you would like to add a new intermediate link (mysite.com/dts/idric/20/ ) as I should do? Thank you