# Rewrite different page with .htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to use .htaccess for url rewrite.
In my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216960/) you have shown me how to do it to the index.php page but now would like to do also for other pages like browser.error.php, etc.
To do so I tried to add the last 2 rows in the .htaccess, but unfortunately if I try the link www.mysite/browser-error/ it doesn't work - Return me in the index page.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L,NC]
# rule to ignore files and directories from all rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\/?$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2&sp=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\/?$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?$ index.php?op=$1 [L,QSA]

#NEW ADDED ROWS
RewriteRule ^browser-error/(.*)\/?$ browser.error.php?r=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^browser-error\/?$ browser.error.php [L]
```

Where I am doing wrong? How would I go? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest avoid use of `.*` and use `[^/]+` instead with re-ordering of your rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L,NC]
# rule to ignore files and directories from all rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#NEW ADDED ROWS
RewriteRule ^browser-error/([^/]+)/?$ browser.error.php?r=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^browser-error/?$ browser.error.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2&sp=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?op=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Seems to be perfect! If you add other rules (comunication.php) I have to make them like those for browser-error? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's correct just add them in the middle before `index.php` rules.

Comment: with same flag ? L, QSA, NC and L, NC?

Comment: yes `[L,QSA,NC]` would be suffice for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have rules before preceding this rule. That makes your petition change to index.php before your rule is reached. (They all have the L flag that makes them be the LAST rule processed). As they are not restricted to not be applied when url is browser-error, they will run on every /*/*/* or simialr petition.

Then, you should add RewriteCond to negate the browser-error url in your other RewriteRules as this:

Please try, and comment if that´s not what you need of it does not work as expected.

Hope it helps

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L,NC]
# rule to ignore files and directories from all rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\/?$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2&sp=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^browser-error\/?(.*)?\/?%
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\/?$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^browser-error\/?(.*)?\/?%
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?$ index.php?op=$1 [L,QSA]

#NEW ADDED ROWS
RewriteRule ^browser-error/(.*)\/?$ browser.error.php?r=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^browser-error\/?$ browser.error.php [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing works, not even the rewrite url to index.php

Comment: i did make a change, sorry (cannot try now here)

Comment: Thank you, but the anubhava solution is perfect for me

Comment: I was goin to tell you this solution was better (reordering thre rules, and cleaning) +1 for him!!!